# Have all the good questions from the Proposal been asked?

Tags: discussion

Have all of the good sample questions from the Proposal phase been officially asked here?

I ask about "good" questions, because I will be the first to admit that my Proposal questions probably aren't a good fit for the official site.  I have only noticed a couple of the highly rated questions appear here.

Comment: Here's the relevant link, for those interested: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453?phase=definition